Oracle Apex Display clob column as link to file
I have a grid in oracle Apex (22.1)
Select fin_id, fin_name,fin_details,fin_desc,fin_unit,fin_results;

FIN_ID->NUMBER
FIN_RESULTS->CLOB
Rest all are varchar2(100)

In grid the fin_results column should dispaly as link which opens a file that shows the output, that is the clob data in a viewable file.
How can this be achieved?
